# Is there a Chow test for higher dimensions?

Tags: structural-change, chow-test

With the original Chow test, you can only test two regressions vs a general one to see a structural change.

Is there a Chow test that can test structural change in 3,4...N regressions for structural changes versus a 'mother' regression at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are extensions of the chow test for multiple breaks, if this is your question?

Bai and Perron investigated test, algorithms, and their distribution, look for example at:

- [Computation and analysis of multiple structural change models](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.659/abstract)
- [Estimating and Testing Linear Models with Multiple Structural Changes](http://www.econ.nyu.edu/user/baij/econometrica98.pdf)

If you are using R, the package [strucchange](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/strucchange.pdf) has many nice features to estimate and test for multiple structural breaks

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my question. That R package is of no use for me as I want to check for structural differences by enacted policies in ARIMA models, whose class is not accepted by strucchange. I had to program the traditional Chow test myself, and took me quite some time, as I'm not a programmer by trade.

Comment: then you could as a gross estimate use strucchange to estimate the breaks on a similar AR() model, where I guess you will need to feed yourself the lags as regressors. Might give you already a rough idea of the possible number of breaks, their location, etc...